# What is the best way to serialise a full graph as GraphSON using gremlin-javascript?

Tags: javascript, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm looking for a single query that can create a GraphSON serialisation of a full TinkerGraph graph.

```
// setup

const gremlin = require('gremlin')

const connection = new gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin')

const g = (new gremlin.structure.Graph()).traversal().withRemote(connection)
```

I'm able to serialise vertices, edges and properties separately as GraphSON. The following statements create a GraphSON serialisation of all vertices only. Edges can be queried with `E()`, and properties with `V().properties()`.

```
// placed within an async function

const writer = new gremlin.structure.io.GraphSONWriter()

const serialisedVertices = writer.write(await g.V().toList())
```

Is there a gremlin-javascript method that will serialise all vertices, edges and properties together (rather than separately as above) into a GraphSON string in a single step?

Additionally if a full graph can be serialised as a single GraphSON string, is there also a matching invokation that will re-hydrate a graph instance from the GraphSON string?

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Which graph server are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm using gremlin server with TinkerGraph, running on a virtual machine accessible via the localhost connection string above. I've edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting gremlin 3.4.x you can use the `io` step:

```
g.io("graph.json").read().iterate()
g.io("graph.json").write().iterate()
```

These commands read/write the complete graph data in graphson format, which is a json file. There are more supported formats as written in the [tinkerpop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#io-step)

If you are running gremlin 3.3.x, you can use the [following command](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/reference/#_gremlin_i_o):

```
graph.io(graphson()).writeGraph("graph.json");
```

Note that the file is stored on the gremlin server current working directory.

Comment: Brilliant thanks - sadly it looks like the `io` property is not found in gremlin-javascript 3.4.3 (http://tinkerpop.apache.org/jsdocs/3.4.3/GraphTraversal.html, also confirmed from logging the objects) so serialising a full graph may not be possible unless there's a more suitable argument to pass to the write() method

Comment: Since it must be the first step in the traversal, it is implemented in GraphTraversalSource. Take a look here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/jsdocs/3.4.3/GraphTraversalSource.html